# MetadataWorkspaceExtensions.GetDbProviderManifest in Entity Framework 6.0

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-6

In EF 5, there was a T4 utility template named `GenerateEDM.Utility.ttinclude` that started with the following code:

```
internal DbProviderManifest GetDbProviderManifest(string providerInvariantName, string providerManifestToken)
{
    DbProviderManifest providerManifest = null;
    try
    {
        providerManifest = MetadataWorkspaceExtensions.GetDbProviderManifest(providerInvariantName, providerManifestToken);
    }
```

Now I'm rewriting some of our EF5 code generation templates for EF6, and I cannot find the method `MetadataWorkspaceExtensions.GetDbProviderManifest`.

**Where was this method moved to in Entity Framework 6.0?**